# Pidora - can't install cheese

Tags: webcam

So I want to use cheese to capture video from my webcam.

When I try to install by

```
yum install cheese
```

I get following errors -

```
Error: Package: 2:cheese-3.4.1-1.fc17.armv6hl (pidora)
       Requires: libgnome-desktop-3.so.2
Error: Package: frei0r-plugins-1.3-8.fc18.1302280219kf.armv6hl (pidora)
       Requires: libopencv_gpu.so.2.4
Error: Package: 2:cheese-3.4.1-1.fc17.armv6hl (pidora)
       Requires: libcogl.so.9
Error: Package: 2:cheese-libs-3.4.1-1.fc17.armv6hl (pidora)
       Requires: libcogl.so.9
Error: Package: frei0r-plugins-1.3-8.fc18.1302280219kf.armv6hl (pidora)
       Requires: libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4
Error: Package: gstreamer-plugins-bad-free-0.10.23-8.fc17.armv6hl (pidora)
       Requires: libvpx.so.0
Error: Package: 2:cheese-libs-3.4.1-1.fc17.armv6hl (pidora)
       Requires: libgnome-desktop-3.so.2
```

The problem is, I can't find which packages to install to meet these dependencies. When I try, I get:

```
No package libgnome-desktop-3.so.2 available.
No package libopencv_gpu.so.2.4 available. 
No package libcogl.so.9 available. 
No package libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4 available. 
No package libvpx.so.0 available. 
No package libgnome-desktop-3.so.2 available. 
Error: Nothing to do
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: I wish I knew what the equivalent of 'apt-cache policy cheese' is in yum.

Answer (score 1):

Each one of those packages needs to be installed.

```
sudo yum install libgnome-desktop-3.so.2 libopencv_gpu.so.2.4 libcogl.so.9 libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4 libvpx.so.0 libgnome-desktop-3.so.2
```

Comment: No package libgnome-desktop-3.so.2 available.
    No package libopencv_gpu.so.2.4 available.
    No package libcogl.so.9 available.
    No package libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4 available.
    No package libvpx.so.0 available.
    No package libgnome-desktop-3.so.2 available.
    Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Based on my googling, it looks like you need to install gnome desktop.

Comment: Installing package gnome-desktop solved absolutely nothing.

Comment: I think those are provided by `gnome-desktop3`; gnome-desktop is version 2.

Comment: No, if a package has dependencies that can't be found, then something is wrong in your repositories!